# Where is the error page location of squid proxy server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I'm using squid proxy server on my Ubuntu 12.04. Where is the error page location so that I can customize it?

Comment: No! I've searched in nook and corner of that squid.conf file. /var/log/syslog contains only system log file.

Comment: Nope It contains all the squid log files (like the web accessed URLs). I need the error page location.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question... Do you have an `error_directory` directive in your configuration ? Error pages should be there.

Comment: No Vinz. I'm looking for that!

Comment: There is no such dierctory. :(

Comment: Can you post the output of `squid -v`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a configured [`error_directory`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/error_directory/) as mentioned, `squid -v` will report your version of squids compile time options.

The following options will impact the path to the error templates:

```
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                      [/usr/local/squid]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
```

The following will impact which error templates are rendered:

```
  --disable-translation   Prevent Squid generating localized error page
  --disable-auto-locale   This prevents Squid providing localized error pages
```

So you end up with `PREFIX/DATADIR/errors/templates` as the default or `PREFIX/DATADIR/errors/$locale/`

Locale can be based on the clients request if using a recent version of Squid or yours was compiled with `--enable-auto-locale` for older versions (3.1)

The [`error_default_language`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/error_default_language/) config option can be involved as well.

Then the `templates` directory is the fallback.

I think this holds true for squid 3.x. Not so sure about 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Error page location is set by the `error_directory` directive.

Comment: Where is that? I need the path!

Comment: According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid/Customize it should be in `/usr/share/squid/errors/<language>/`. If it does not exist, I suggest you to generate an error and strace the process to see where it looks for these pages.

Comment: I've seen that page. but it is of no use.

Comment: Another solution would be to save the HTML error page on your harddisk, make the changes you want, add an `error_directory` directive in your configuration file, and put your new file in this directory.

Comment: I did that prior asking question here.